# what is the best way to handle double value while split?

Tags: java

```
String x = "39.33";
String result ;
Double x1 = new Double(x);
System.err.println("value :"+ x1);
String[] parts = x1.toString().split("\\.");

if(parts != null )
{
 if((Integer.parseInt(parts[1])) > 0)
{
       result =x1;

}
 else
{
result= parts[0];
}
 }
```

please let me know the best way to format/split the value:
my need is....

```
 if x is 39
 so x1 is 39.0
 so i need result =39

 if x is 39.33
 so x1 is 39.33
 so i need result =39.33
```

i dont want to use split or condition checking `if((Integer.parseInt(parts[1])) > 0)`.. please let me know the best way for this?

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: is it any difference between 39.0 and 39? if you need this distinction when you display value, just format your output before you do it

Comment: i have input like("39.33" or "39.0")... if input is "39.33" result must be 39.33 or if input is "39.0" result must be 39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble("35.0");
String result = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(d.doubleValue())
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: wow.. i really looked answer like this only.. 100% satisfied my expectation

Comment: Double d = Double.parseDouble("35.0");
String result = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(d))

Comment: why do we neeed d.doubleValue())

Answer (score 1):

if you convert your double to an int the decimal places are ignored.

for this problem it would be something like that:

```
String result;
String x = "39.33";
Double x1 = new Double(x);
int xPre = x1.intValue();

if ( x1 > xPre) {
    result = x1;
} else {
    result = Integer.toString(xPre);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code as an example to make this clearer?

Comment: its giving only 39 in either case("39.33" or "39.0")... i need like if "39.33" result must be 39.33 or if "39.0" result must be 39

Comment: i hope the comparison of the double and int works ... but try it and give feedback...

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to read the number as a double and cast it to an int, which will effectively truncate the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
String x = "39.33";
long l = (long) Double.parseDouble(x); // == 39
```

This will result in `l` being the whole number part of the double. (provided the number is less than 9 billion billion)

If you really want to use split you can do the following which will be slightly slower but will throw an exception if the number is too large.

```
long l = Long.parseLong(x.split("\\.")[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, provided the number is less than 2 billion.  IMHO there is no advantage in using an `int`.

Comment: @Abu.. Yes, provided the number is less than 4 billion or so. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey. Lolzz. :) Did I just increased the size of int?

Comment: @RohitJain Perhaps contaminated by `unsigned int` from somewhere ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double x = new Double("39.33");
    Double y = new Double("39.0");

   printDouble(x);
   printDouble(y);

}

public static void printDouble(Double dbl){
    System.out.println(dbl.toString().replaceAll("[0]*$", "").replaceAll(".$", ""));
}
```